# How to initialize an array subelement in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently trying to implement an array read using Vue:

```
{{ this.locations[this.record.carton.LocationID - 1].Location }}
```

While the code itself works fine during run time, it throws the following error when its first loaded:

```
app.js:55125 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Location')"

app.js:56401 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Location')
    at Proxy.render (app.js:49569:28)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:58068:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:58580:21)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:58994:25)
    at new Watcher (app.js:58983:12)
    at mountComponent (app.js:58587:3)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:63593:10)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:66507:16)
    at init (app.js:57639:13)
    at merged (app.js:57824:5)
```

I've tried initializing the value of Location like so, but it doesn't seem to help

```
return {
     data() {
        return {
            locations: {
                Location: ''
            },
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `this.locations[this.record.carton.LocationID - 1]?.Location ?? ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general purpose way to solve is to setup either defaults or guards or both.

Defaults - like you tried, except with an array, and taking care that the index expression works out to the defaulted index...

```
return {
   data() {
      return {
        locations: [{ Location: '' }],
        record: { carton: { LocationID: 1 } }
      }
   }
 }
```

But that seems a little contrived and brittle. The alternative is to guard the markup with v-if...

```
<div v-if="record && record.carton && locations && record.carton.LocationID - 1 < locations.length">
  {{ locations[record.carton.LocationID - 1].Location }}
</div>
```

That expression is involved enough to warrant placing it in aa method.